# Insert in dictionary in type script

Tags: angular

I need to filter a dictionary in angular. I used the following code, however, I cant insert the selected items into my final dictionary! Anyone knows how to solve it? Thanks.

```
filterData(data: any): any{
   for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++){
      if(data[x].status == "true"){
         this.filteredData.push(data[x]); // Doesn't work!
      }
   }            
   return this.filteredData;     
}
```

filteredData is already defined in my .ts file.

Comment: What is the type of `this.filteredData`?  And why defeat the type system with any here?

Answer (score 0):

you need return a "new Array" (not the modified array ), see this [SO](https://https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74989861/pure-pipe-updating-array-in-ui-which-is-not-supposed-to-happen/74989966#74989966).

So generally you have a function

```
filterData(data: any[]): any{
  //you can use directly the filter method of an array(*)
  return data.filter(x.status=="true")
}
```

And use

```
this.filteredData=this.filterData(this.data)
```

See that you're creating a new array

( * ) to know about differents methods of array see, [e.g. for filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I got an error: Cannot find name 'x'.