# Pure pipe updating array in UI which is not supposed to happen

Tags: angular, pipe

I was exploring Pipe functions in Angular and got to know that for non-primitive data types like arrays , even if there is a change in the array's elements the pipe function would not apply to the updated array and would be applied for the initial array itself. That is why when we add new elements pipe functions are not added to these new elements of the array.

But when I tried deleting, adding and updating existing elements of an array with a pipe function it worked. However, the changes the array should not be reflected to the UI as the pipe funciton is a pure one. Please let me know why the changes of an array are being reflected when the pipe is pure.

pipe.TS:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'arrayPipe',
  // pure:false
})
export class ArrayPipePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number[]) {
    value.pop();
    value.push(4);
    value[1]=5;
    console.log(value);
    return (value);
  }
}
```

app.HTML:

```
<div>{{trialArray}}</div>
<div>{{trialArray | arrayPipe }}</div>
```

app.component.TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  trialArray = [1,2,3];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

question: When Angular know that "something" change?

answer: when his value change

The problem with arrays (and objects) are that not change when change some value (or some property) of it, else if change the "position in memory". This is the reason you need "create a new array". Generally you use the "spread operator"

```
this.trialArray=[...this.trialArray] //the ... are the spread operator
```

This is the reason because it's not a good aproach use pipe to transform an array (even a pipe sort)

In the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bt4h7y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) if you comment the line

```
this.trialArray=[...this.trialArray]
```

You can not see the array correctly

Of course you can create a pipe "impure". When you declare the pipe you write `pure:false`

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'arrayPipe',pure:false //<--see the "pure:false"
})
export class ArrayPipe implements PipeTransform{
   transform(value: any[], args?: any): any {
      return value.map((x) => x * 2);
   }
}
```

This makes that you can "change" the array (without create a copy) and show the result. But see that in this case the array in .html is not updated

```
<div>{{trialArray}}</div>  //<--this show always [1,2,3]
<div>{{trialArray | arrayPipe }}</div>  //<--this change when "click"

click(){
  this.trialArray.push(4);
}
```

but this makes that "In this case, the pipe is invoked on each change-detection cycle, even if the arguments have not changed.", see the docs.

We can see adding a console.log("here") in the function transform

**About the pipe** in the question there're two problems

1. Change the value of the array. We can solve make a copy before (we
   can use the sprred operator

   ```
   export class ArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {
     transform(value: any[], args?: any): any {
       const result=[...value] //make a copy
       result.pop();   //change the copy
       result.push(4);
       result[1]=5;
       return result
     }
   }
   ```
2. if we want we can convert the pipe to impure adding `pure:false`
   when create

Comment: could u update my Pipe.TS code without changing the existing code? It would really help me get a better understanding of it.